# dhcp3-server (dhcpd) is tampering with host NIC

Tags: dhcp

I have a debian box that is serving as a router (using iptables NAT). When first turned on, everything works fine for a few minutes. Then the dhcp server assigns an IP (other than 192.168.0.1) to its' host NIC, eth0. This is NOT what I want. I just want dhcp3-server to listen on eth0, not assign it an IP, and changes the kernel routing table. This of course ruins the NAT capablities of the box. How can I tell the dhcp3-server NOT to do this?

Thanks

Before dhcp3-server tampers with eth0, the IP is **192.168.0.1**, and the routing table looks like this:

> ~# netstat -r
>   Kernel IP routing table 
>  
>   Destination     Gateway         Iface 
>  
>   192.168.0.0     *               eth0 
>  
>   173.33.220.0    *               eth1 
>  
>   default         **173.33.220.1**    eth1

After dhcp3-server tampers with eth0, the IP is **192.168.0.3**, and the routing table looks like this:

> ~# netstat -r
>   Kernel IP routing table 
>  
>   Destination     Gateway         Iface 
>  
>   192.168.0.0     *               eth0 
>  
>   173.33.220.0    *               eth1 
>  
>   default         **192.168.0.1**     eth0 
>  
>   default         **173.33.220.1**    eth1

**SETUP**

Outbound NIC is eth1 
Internal NIC is eth0

/etc/network/interfaces

> ... 
>  
>   iface eth0 inet static 
>   address 192.168.0.1 
>   netmask 255.255.255.0

/etc/default/dhcp3-server

> INTERFACES="eth0"

Answer (score -1):

So I figured out this DHCP problem, in case anyone runs across it. My kernel routing tables were being trampled by an updated route besides the external nic. It turns out that dhcpd3 needs dhclient in order to operate. dhclient makes lease requests for dhcpd3 (don't think server works without client). dhclient configures the logical interface based on the information it gets from dhcpd3.

What I had to do was explicitly request dhcp information, WITHOUT the router data. The 'dhclient.conf' file is below.

```
~$ more /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf

...
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes;
...

interface "eth0" {
  send dhcp-client-identifier 1:70:71:bc:43:55:44;
  send dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, domain-name, domain-name-servers, host-name;   # 'router' option NOT included 

}
interface "eth1" {
  send dhcp-client-identifier 1:00:1f:1f:b1:e5:9e;
  send dhcp-lease-time 86400;
}

...
```

Good-luck

Comment: The dhcp server does not require the dhcp client in order to operate.  You can happily run one without the other, depending on your particular needs.  The dhcp client is only necessary if you expect to configure your network interfaces using dhcp -- which, arguably, doesn't make much sense on a system acting as a dhcp server.  Additionally, the dhcp server does not modify your routing tables or network interface configuration; this only happens when the *client* acquires a new lease, and it only happens indirectly via the `dhclient-script`.